# Side by side video with multiple single image sources

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-filters

I'm creating 4 video files with 4 different single images sources (with pattern_type glob):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 2 -pattern_type glob -i './1/*.jpg' -y out_1.mp4
ffmpeg -framerate 2 -pattern_type glob -i './2/*.jpg' -y out_2.mp4
ffmpeg -framerate 2 -pattern_type glob -i './3/*.jpg' -y out_3.mp4
ffmpeg -framerate 2 -pattern_type glob -i './4/*.jpg' -y out_4.mp4
```

The jpeg source files are in subfolders and named like this:

```
./1/00000025.jpg
./1/00000050.jpg
./1/00000075.jpg
...

./2/00000025.jpg
./2/00000050.jpg
./2/00000075.jpg
...

./3/00000025.jpg
./3/00000050.jpg
./3/00000075.jpg
...

./4/00000025.jpg
./4/00000050.jpg
./4/00000075.jpg
...
```

After creating the single mp4 files, I combine them into one single mp4, using the xstack filter:

```
ffmpeg -i ./out_1.mp4 -i ./out_2.mp4 -i ./out_3.mp4 -i ./out_4.mp4 -lavfi "xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0" visor_combined_PS01.mp4
```

to display the 4 inputs into 2x2 grid like this:

```
[1][2]
[3][4]
```

Is it possible to combine these steps? Directly create a side by side video with 4 image sources?

Comment: try to replace `-i ./out_1.mp4` with `-framerate 2 -pattern_type glob -i './1/*.jpg'` etc

Comment: @hscho that's unrelated to the question. This is not a discussion forum, you shouldn't ask irrelevant additional questions in comments.